# Spring JPA CrudRepository Autowired object is null when used with Apache Commons Tailer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, apache-commons

I'm working on a small app that I can point to an Apache HTTP server log, follow the log (a la 'tail -f' in Linux), and write entries to an Oracle Database table.

I set up Spring Boot / Spring Data JPA application and created classes for my Entity, the `CrudRepository` interface, a service for the interface (though I believed this technically unnecessary for this implementation), and a runner to kick the process off. I also set up the `TailerListenerAdapter` to do the lifting for the log file parsing. I will post all of this code below.

The problem is that I can write a test record to the database successfully *prior* to starting the Tailer listener. However, when the listener is running, the Autowired Service in the `TailerListenerAdapter`, is null and throws an exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sbx.demo.logauditor.util.AccessListener.handle(AccessListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer.readLines(Tailer.java:525)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer.run(Tailer.java:457)
    at sbx.demo.logauditor.LogAuditRunner.run(LogAuditRunner.java:40)
    {... more stack trace ...}
```

Here are the classes used (I probably have some unnecessary annotations in there left from experimentation) -

**LogAuditRunner.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.var;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.model.AccessRecord;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.service.AccessService;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.util.AccessListener;

@Component
public class LogAuditRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    AccessService accServ;
    final String datePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // This test code works if uncommented
        //LocalDateTime TS = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse("31/Jan/2020:14:28:32 -0500"));     
        //var logTest = new AccessRecord("10.154.103.2",Timestamp.valueOf(TS),"/cs/resources/layouts/Top%20Menus/Oracle/tree_T_collection_closed.gif","304");
        //System.out.println("Testing repository with " + logTest.toString());
        //accServ.save(logTest);

        TailerListener listener = new AccessListener();    
        Tailer tailer = new Tailer(new File("D:\\access_log"), listener);        
        tailer.run();
    }

}
```

**AccessService.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import sbx.demo.logauditor.model.AccessRecord;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.repository.AccessRepository;

@Service
@Configurable
public class AccessService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    AccessRepository accessRepo;

    public void save(AccessRecord ar) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Writing record to database: " + ar.toString());
            accessRepo.save(ar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<AccessRecord> findAll() {
        List<AccessRecord> recList = new ArrayList<AccessRecord>();
        try {
            System.out.println("Searching database for all access records");

            for(AccessRecord ar : accessRepo.findAll()) {
                recList.add(ar);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return recList;
    }
}
```

**AccessRepository.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import sbx.demo.logauditor.model.AccessRecord;

@Repository
public interface AccessRepository extends CrudRepository<AccessRecord, Long>{
}
```

**AccessRecord.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor.model; 

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="ACCESS_LOG")
@Data
public class AccessRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="PROXY_AGENT")
    private String agent;
    @Column(name="SOURCE_IP")
    private String sourceip;
    @Column(name="ACCESS_TS")
    private Timestamp reqts;
    @Column(name="URI")
    private String requri;
    @Column(name="HTTP_STATUS")
    private String respcode;

    public AccessRecord() {}

    public AccessRecord(String source, Timestamp ts, String uri, String status) {
        this.sourceip = source;
        this.reqts = ts;
        this.requri = uri;
        this.respcode = status;

        try {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String hostname = ip.getHostName();
            this.agent = hostname;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String record = "Record: [" +  agent + "] [" + sourceip + "] [" + reqts +  "] [" + requri +  "] [" + respcode + "]";

        return record;
    }
}
```

**AccessListener.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor.util;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.var;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.model.AccessRecord;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.repository.AccessRepository;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.service.AccessService;

@Component
public class AccessListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    final String regex = "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) " + 
            "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(\\S+)" + 
            " (\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)?\\s*\" (\\d{3}) (\\S+)"; 
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final String datePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);

    @Autowired
    AccessService accServ;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void handle(String line) {
        LogRecorder lr = new LogRecorder();
        try {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String IP = matcher.group(1);
                //String TS = matcher.group(4);
                String URL = matcher.group(6);
                String STATUS = matcher.group(8);

                LocalDateTime TS = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(matcher.group(4)));


                var ar = new AccessRecord(IP,Timestamp.valueOf(TS),URL,STATUS);
                accServ.save(ar);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

And finally **LogauditorApplication.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LogauditorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LogauditorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Side note, I noticed that if I manually instantiate the `AccessService` (instead of relying on Autowiring), I can invoke it, but then the `NullPointerException` happens on the Autowired `AccessRepository` interface. It's clear to me that it has to do with the Autowiring, I just am not understanding why.

I know that there are ways to follow and send logs via command line (this is going to run in a Linux environment) but I want to ensure that it is robust enough to, say, restart if it dies, handle log rollovers, etc. Also, I'm planning to write in some extra validation to ensure entries don't overlap (i.e. - in the event the application restarts and re-reads an entire file). But, I wanted to get it working first. I thought it would be straightforward since Tailer requires so little code, and I'm already comfortable with Spring.

Comment: What is the Spring Boot version? Can you create one constructor in `AccessListener` taking an `AccessService` parameter, and omit the `@Autowired` as per Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection). What's the output?

Comment: @Boris Spring Boot version is 2.2.4.RELEASE. I did as you suggested and made the ```AccessService``` part of the ```AccessListener``` constructor. I'm able to execute the application without the NullPointerExceptions now, and I can see SQL debug in my logs. However, the data is not being committed to the database. I assume the transaction is being held open?

Comment: @Boris I was able to fix it by adding the ```@Transactional``` annotation to the ```AccessService``` _save_ method.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by passing the `AccessService` as a parameter for the `AccessListener` constructor. I then had to add the `@Transactional` annotation to the *save* method in the `AccessService` so that transactions would commit after each line was processed inside the thread.

New **AccessListener.java**

```
package sbx.demo.logauditor.util;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter;

import sbx.demo.logauditor.model.AccessRecord;
import sbx.demo.logauditor.service.AccessService;

public class AccessListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    final String regex = "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) " + 
            "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(\\S+)" + 
            " (\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)?\\s*\" (\\d{3}) (\\S+)"; 
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final String datePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
    private AccessService accServ;

    public AccessListener(AccessService as) {
        this.accServ = as;
    }

//  @Autowired
//  AccessService accServ;

    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        try {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String IP = matcher.group(1);
                String URL = matcher.group(6);
                String STATUS = matcher.group(8);

                LocalDateTime TS = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(matcher.group(4)));


                AccessRecord ar = new AccessRecord(IP,Timestamp.valueOf(TS),URL,STATUS);
                accServ.save(ar);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```